How to slow down my objects when they are initialized?
I'm working with React Three Fiber (I'm a beginner in this) and when the scene is mounted and the objects appear in it, they'll are going in random directions (which is okay) but with a high velocity, and I think it's because they appear at the same position of others or they appear in one of the collision walls, but I'm not sure about this.
What I'm searching for is a space with 0 gravity and a few objects floating in this space, and if they collide, the objects change their direction. I'm not adding damping or friction because I don't want to slow down their velocity with the time passing by, only reduce the velocity when the scene and objects are mount and maintain that velocity.
before you read my code: It's only a "test", that's why it's all made in one file (which is App.jsx), soon if I fix this problem, I'm going to apply some architecture for the structure of the folders and archives.
The code:
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, useGLTF, Plane, Environment } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Physics, useSphere, usePlane, Debug } from "@react-three/cannon";

import "./App.css";

function Model() {
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: "#C3C3C3" });
  const { nodes } = useGLTF("./cross.glb");

  return (
    <mesh
      castShadow
      receiveShadow
      geometry={nodes.connector.geometry}
      material={material}
      scale={10}
    />
  );
}

function FloatingObject({ position }) {
  const [ref, api] = useSphere(() => ({
    mass: 10,
    position,
    args: [1],
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    api.velocity.set(
      (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1,
      (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1,
      (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.1
    );

    api.angularVelocity.set(
      (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1,
      (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1,
      (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1
    );
  }, [api]);

  return (
    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <Model />
    </mesh>
  );
}
FloatingObject.propTypes = {
  position: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number).isRequired,
};

function CollisionBox() {
  usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0],
    position: [0, -10, 0],
  })); // Bottom
  usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [Math.PI / 2, 0, 0],
    position: [0, 10, 0],
  })); // Top
  usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [0, Math.PI / 2, 0],
    position: [-10, 0, 0],
  })); // Left
  usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [0, -Math.PI / 2, 0],
    position: [10, 0, 0],
  })); // Right
  usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [0, 0, 0],
    position: [0, 0, -10],
  })); // Back
  usePlane(() => ({
    rotation: [0, Math.PI, 0],
    position: [0, 0, 10],
  })); // Front

  return (
    <>
      <Plane
        args={[20, 20]}
        rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
        position={[0, -10, 0]}
      >
        <meshBasicMaterial color="lightblue" opacity={0.5} transparent />
      </Plane>
      <Plane
        args={[20, 20]}
        rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
        position={[0, 10, 0]}
      >
        <meshBasicMaterial color="lightblue" opacity={0.5} transparent />
      </Plane>
      <Plane
        args={[20, 20]}
        rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
        position={[-10, 0, 0]}
      >
        <meshBasicMaterial color="lightgreen" opacity={0.5} transparent />
      </Plane>
      <Plane
        args={[20, 20]}
        rotation={[0, -Math.PI / 2, 0]}
        position={[10, 0, 0]}
      >
        <meshBasicMaterial color="lightgreen" opacity={0.5} transparent />
      </Plane>
      <Plane args={[20, 20]} rotation={[0, 0, 0]} position={[0, 0, -10]}>
        <meshBasicMaterial color="lightcoral" opacity={0.5} transparent />
      </Plane>
      <Plane args={[20, 20]} rotation={[0, Math.PI, 0]} position={[0, 0, 10]}>
        <meshBasicMaterial color="lightcoral" opacity={0.5} transparent />
      </Plane>
    </>
  );
}

function Scene() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />

      <Physics gravity={[0, 0, 0]}>
        <Debug color="black" scale={1.1}>
          <CollisionBox />

          {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, i) => (
            <FloatingObject
              key={i}
              position={[
                Math.random() * 8 - 2,
                Math.random() * 8 - 2,
                Math.random() * 8 - 2,
              ]}
            />
          ))}
        </Debug>
      </Physics>

      <OrbitControls />
      <Environment preset="studio" />
    </Canvas>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div id="canvas">
      <Scene />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

